# regex to validate decimal number

Tags: ios, regex

I have a requirement to validate a decimal number, that is integer part can have upto 5 characters and the fraction value can have upto 2 chars. (fraction value is optional). I have tried a lot and I m endup with below expression.

```
"^([0-9]{0,5})((.|,)[0-9]{0,2})?$"
```

Everything is fine except the non decimal value (Where there is no ./, present).

ie. the expression accepts `99999999`

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why use a regex? Use `NSNumberFormatter`. Then you can properly deal with numbers entered by users from different locales.

Comment: @rmaddy NSNumberFormatter gave proper number for 999.999  though i give maximumFractionDigits = 2

Comment: Can you share me an example that will suite my case?

Comment: You need to replace zero with one in the 2nd limiting quantifier. Try `"^[0-9]{0,5}(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?$"`.

Comment: Hi , you want allow user to give input as above format or , u want check whether given input is in proper format or not?

Comment: @AndeySatyanarayana I want user to be able to enter in above format

Comment: are you using textfield to take input?

Comment: @AndeySatyanarayana YES

Comment: once check my answer , i hope it will help you

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your regex is the dot: without proper escaping, the dot character ('.') accepts any character except line break (see this [quick reference](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#morechars)).

In order to represent a literal dot, you must escape it with backslash ('\'), so your regex ends up looking like this:

```
"^([0-9]{0,5})((\.|,)[0-9]{0,2})?$"
```

Comment: Not slowed the issue

Answer (score 0):

This expression passes

```
"^([0-9]{0,5}+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$"
```

Thanks everyone who tried help me.

Answer (score -1):

// trye like this

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
            return YES;
        }
        if(string.length > 1 ) {
            return NO;
        }
        if ([textField.text rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound) {
            if([string rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound) {
                return NO;
            }
            NSString *strTemptext = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@"$#"];
            NSArray *arrComponants = [strTemptext componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"];
            NSString *strText = @"";
            if (arrComponants.count > 0) {
                if([(NSString *)[arrComponants objectAtIndex:0] containsString:@"#"]) {
                    strText = [arrComponants objectAtIndex:0];
                } else {
                    strText = [arrComponants objectAtIndex:1];
                }
            } else {
                strText = [arrComponants objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            if([strText length] >= 3) {
                return NO;
            }

        }
        if(textField.text.length >= 5 && [textField.text rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound && [string rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound) {
            return NO;
        }
        if( [textField.text rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound && textField.text.length > 7) {
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
}
```